# maven try to include bungee.myl file into my uber jar

Tags: java, maven, minecraft

Im working with Eclipse IDE and Java. The few last days i worked a lot with maven. Now i try to put the bungee.yml file into my, with maven shade plugin generated, jar-file. I look in the documentation and try to use "IncludeResourceTransformer" but when i execute mvn clean install the bungee.yml file dont include in the new jar file.

pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>de.falco.essentialsXXX</groupId>
  <artifactId>EssentialsXXX-bungeecord</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <description>Basic class for every Plugin</description>



  <build>
  
    <finalName>test</finalName>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    
    <!-- COMPILE -->
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.0</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.8</source>
          <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.4</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>shade</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                            <transformers>
                                <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.IncludeResourceTransformer">
                                    <resource>/</resource>
                                    <file>bungee.yml</file>
                                </transformer>
                            </transformers>
            
              <artifactSet>
                <excludes>
                  <exclude>net.md-5:bungeecord-api</exclude>
                  <exclude>net.luckperms:api</exclude>
                </excludes>
              </artifactSet>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      
      
      
    </plugins>
  </build>

<repositories>
    <repository>
       <id>bungeecord-repo</id>
       <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots</url>
   </repository>
</repositories>
  
  <dependencies>
  
    <dependency>
       <groupId>net.luckperms</groupId>
       <artifactId>api</artifactId>
       <version>5.0</version>
    </dependency>
  
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
        <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
       <groupId>net.md-5</groupId>
       <artifactId>bungeecord-api</artifactId>
       <version>1.16-R0.2-SNAPSHOT</version>
       <type>jar</type>
       <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
       <groupId>net.md-5</groupId>
       <artifactId>bungeecord-api</artifactId>
       <version>1.16-R0.2-SNAPSHOT</version>
       <type>javadoc</type>
       <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    
  </dependencies>
  
</project>
```

ATTENTION: my bungee.yml file is in the same directory as pom.xml

Q: How should i include my bungee.yml file in my uber jar?

Comment: Did you try putting in the resource folder ?

Comment: Why have you changed the convention into `<sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>` ?

Comment: @rootkonda what do you mean with resource folder?

Comment: @khmarbaise ich use <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory> to compile my source code in the src directory

Comment: Your answer is simply not helpful cause I know what the `sourceDirectory` is intended to do and what not. Furthermore already asked the same question? Does not make sense https://stackoverflow.com/q/63160213/296328 . The default layout in Maven projects is https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html and should be followed (except you know exactly what you are doing which does not like that you know that). So best follow the convention.

Comment: As far as I know, and per the [official example](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/examples/resource-transformers.html#IncludeResourceTransformer), the target location should include the filename, so try replacing `<resource>/</resource>` by `<resource>/bungee.yml</resource>` or `<resource>bungee.yml</resource>`.